# How can I connect to multiple BLE devices simultaneously in android?

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to connect to more than one ble devices at a time in android. I can connect to single device at a time and can pass the data between them. For achieving the single connection I used the code from following link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt . How can I make multiple connections at a time? Is there any sample code for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the API that stops you from connecting to multiple devices at the same time. Just execute [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context, boolean, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)) to each device (until the internal limit is reached).